# How can I check in CMake whether a list contains a specific entry?

Tags: cmake

I want to check whether a lists contains a specific entry like in the following code snippet:

```
macro(foo)
if ($(ARGN} contains "bar")
  ...
endif
endmacro()
```

CMake does not offer a `contains`. What is best / easiest way to get the desired result?

In CMake's [wiki](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMakeMacroListOperations#LIST_CONTAINS), I found a `LIST_CONTAINS` macro, but the wiki page is outdated. Is this still the best way to go, or has CMake gained new capabilities?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

With CMake 3.3 or later, the `if` command supports an `IN_LIST` [operator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html), e.g.:

```
if ("bar" IN_LIST _list)
 ...
endif()
```

For older versions of CMake, you can use the built-in [list(FIND)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:list) function:

```
list (FIND _list "bar" _index)
if (${_index} GREATER -1)
  ...
endif()
```

Comment: I didn't recommend this for a couple of reasons.  In the scope of a macro (as per the OP), you'd have to copy `ARGN` or this would fail silently.  Also, this is significantly slower for large lists than my answer.

Comment: @Fraser Why would this silently fail?

Comment: I had to add quotation marks around the first argument `"${ARGN}"`. Maybe this is related to to Fraser's comment.

Comment: The [docs for `macro`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/macro.html#macro-argument-caveats), particularly the caveats, explain it.  If you try `list(FIND ARGN "bar" _index)` inside a `macro` it will always set `_index` to -1 since `ARGN` isn't a normal variable here.

Comment: I've found that these commands are very fragile, e.g. `if("cxx_std_20" IN_LIST ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_FEATURES})` fails, while `if("cxx_std_20" IN_LIST my_list)` works.

Answer (score 12):

Fewer lines:

```
if (";${ARGN};" MATCHES ";bar;")
  #  ...
endif()
```

But see the `IN_LIST` syntax from @sakra for a more-modern syntax.

Answer (score 7):

I have been using one liner like `if ("${PLATFORM}" MATCHES "^(os|ios|android|linux|win32)$")` to check if `PLATFORM` is in the list

Comment: It might be ok for your use case, but does not work in general. (a) You have to know the list, a dynamic list does not work. (b) The list is limited to a dozen of entries, otherwise it is difficult to maintain. (c) It is less obvious to the reader, what this cold is supposed to do. (d) MATCHES is slow, because it uses a regular expression.

Answer (score 4):

If the intention here is to add a value to a list *but only if it's not already in the list*, then an alternative approach is to just add it to the list and immediately remove possible duplicates again:

```cmake
list(APPEND            SOME_LIST "value")
list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES SOME_LIST)
```

Comment: Would be interesting to get some numbers to compare the performance. Code-wise it is good to read.