# In CMake, how do I add to a compiler flag only if it isn't used already?

Tags: cmake, duplicates, compiler-flags

I'm using CMake, and I want to add a compilation flag to some flags variable. For example, I want to add `-DFOO` to the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE` variable.

Right now, I use:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -DFOO" )
```

... but if there already is a `-DFOO` flag, I get it double, which might be harmless but I'd rather avoid it. Assuming I can't control whether or not there's a `-DFOO` to begin with - how can I "add a flag only if it's missing" to such a flags variable?

**Notes:**

- An answer regarding adding elements to a space-separated-list variable in general will suffice, I guess.
- My `CMakeLists.txt` requires CMake v2.8 at the least; but if you have an answer which requires a newer version (3.x ?), that would also be relevant.

Comment: Is this enough? http://stackoverflow.com/q/23323147/2799037 You have to do the conversion to a list yourself though.

Comment: @usr1234567: I would rather avoid converting the list, checking, adding the flag, then converting the list back...

Comment: I'd use `string(FIND `.

Comment: which version of CMake are you using or you plan to use (a.k.a what's the minimum required version you set in CMakeLists.txt)?

Comment: @fedepad: It's not about what I'm using, but what I'm requiring. Right now I require v2.8 .

Comment: You could use: `string(FIND <string> <substring> <output variable>)` as mentioned by @usr1234567 or `if(<variable|string> MATCHES regex)` or `string(REGEX MATCH <regular_expression>
       <output variable> <input>)`. `if(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE MATCHES "-DFOO")` seems to work for me, I tried. I could put it in an answer if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you could use the following syntax:

```
if(<variable|string> MATCHES regex)
```

which according to the documentation (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/if.html) evaluates to

> True if the given string or variable’s value matches the given regular
>   expression.

A minimum working example that replicates yours:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -DFOO" )
if( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE MATCHES "-DFOO")
        message("matching -DFOO")
        message("${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE}")
else( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE MATCHES "-DFOO")
        message("no -DFOO!!!")
        message("${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE}")
endif()
```

will print

> ```
> matching -DFOO
> -O3 -DNDEBUG -DFOO
> ```

while the following

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE}" )
if( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE MATCHES "-DFOO")
        message("matching -DFOO")
        message("${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE}")
else( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE MATCHES "-DFOO")
        message("no -DFOO!!!")
        message("${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE}")
endif()
```

will print

> ```
> no -DFOO!!!
> -O3 -DNDEBUG
> ```

You could achieve similar results by using the followings:

```
string(REGEX MATCH <regular_expression> <output variable> <input>)
```

or

```
string(FIND <string> <substring> <output variable>)
```

the last one previously suggested by @usr1234567 in a comment.
So you could put the

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -DFOO" )
```

inside the `if()` statement as a solution.

Comment: Nice... I just need to put that if-then-else block into some kind of function so I don't have to replicate it everywhere.

Comment: Oh yes, you can do it! I just replicated the small example just to see if it was working in this case... ;)

Comment: You need to be careful with your choice of regex otherwise other flags, e.g. `-NOT-DFOO` or `-DFOOLPROOF`, will inappropriately match.