# Correctly passing Command Line arguments to clang/LLVM

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, llvm

I have a custom LLVM pass that can be activated by using a command line option:

```
static cl::opt<bool> MyPass("mypass", cl::init(false));
```

Now, using `clang` I can invoke the pass like this: `clang -mllvm -mypass`.

Building projects, e.g. with CMake, I would pass the argument to CMake using `-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-mllvm -mypass" -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-mllvm -mypass"`

This has been working for me for a couple of projects, but now I have tried to build LLVM itself using my pass. Using the above declaration for the boolean flag I would get an error during the build:

> clang (LLVM option parsing): for the -mypass option: may only occur zero or one times!

I always thought that when there are duplicate flags (`CFLAGS`/`CXXFLAGS`) only the last one would count. This would not be bad in my case, because it's just a boolean flag.

The LLVM documentation shows that there is another cl option that can be used: `cl::ZeroOrMore`. This solved the error message above. (*)

However, this led to the next error:

> llvm-tblgen: /LLVM/src/lib/Support/CommandLine.cpp:278: void (anonymous namespace)::CommandLineParser::registerCategory(llvm::cl::OptionCategory *): Assertion `count_if(RegisteredOptionCategories, [cat](const OptionCategory *Category) { return cat->getName() == Category->getName(); }) == 0 && "Duplicate option categories"' failed.

This happens with the above solution to the previous error as well as with the alternative solution (*) (**).

My question now is: am I passing the argument incorrectly? Is this simply a question of how the CMakeLists.txt and/or Makefiles are organised (e.g. by reusing `CFLAGS` for `CXXFLAGS`, thus duplicating custom flags)?

If possible, I would like to solve this without having to modify LLVM internals.

---

(*) Another way to solve this was specifying either `CFLAGS` or `CXXFLAGS`, although I would like to have the pass run on both C and C++ code.

(**) Actually, specifying only `CFLAGS` when building LLVM works fine, because the few C files don't trigger the error for whatever reason. Specifying `CXXFLAGS` however, does.

---

**Edit**
Regarding comments about CMake & possible duplicate:

This is not a duplicate of the referenced question - I'm not looking to modify the project's build-system, but instead just pass an additional flag to clang/llvm (via command line argument).
Basically, I would want to download sources for any project and then build that project (with my pass) without having to modify its CMakeLists.txt.

Stacktrace for the assertion error:

> llvm-tblgen: /LLVM/src/lib/Support/CommandLine.cpp:278: void (anonymous namespace)::CommandLineParser::registerCategory(llvm::cl::OptionCategory *): Assertion `count_if(RegisteredOptionCategories, [cat](const OptionCategory *Category) { return cat->getName() == Category->getName(); }) == 0 && "Duplicate option categories"' failed.
>   Aborted (core dumped)
>   tools/clang/include/clang/Driver/CMakeFiles/ClangDriverOptions.dir/build.make:91: recipe for target 'tools/clang/include/clang/Driver/Options.inc.tmp' failed
>   make[2]: * * * [tools/clang/include/clang/Driver/Options.inc.tmp] Error 134
>   CMakeFiles/Makefile2:20791: recipe for target 'tools/clang/include/clang/Driver/CMakeFiles/ClangDriverOptions.dir/all' failed
>   make[1]: * * * [tools/clang/include/clang/Driver/CMakeFiles/ClangDriverOptions.dir/all] Error 2
>   make[1]: * * * Waiting for unfinished jobs....

Comment: Is there a stack trace accompanying that assertion failure?

Comment: `I always thought that when there are duplicate flags only the last one would count.` No. CMake has no idea about duplicates and won't eliminate/override them in any way. It will pass them as-is to the compiler. Also note that you should add the `CMakeLists.txt` because as it stands it's probably not solvable without it.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41545768/2799037